# Split vector after each occurance of an element

Tags: clojure

This should be easy but I'm finding it more difficult than expected.

Given `[0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1]`, split the sequence after each occurance of `2`.

Result should be similar to `[[0 1 2] [0 1 2] [0 1]]`.

`split` functions only split at the first instance. My imagination is also limited on how to use the `partition` functions to achieve this.

Comment: Do you need to split vector of numbers or vector of arbitrary objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

previous solutions are ok (although @magos solution if flawed in some cases), but if this function is to be used as an utility (it is rather general i guess), i would use the classic iterative approach:

```
(defn group-loop [delim coll]
  (loop [res [] curr [] coll (seq coll)]
    (if coll
      (let [group (conj curr (first coll))]
        (if (= delim (first coll))
          (recur (conj res group) [] (next coll))
          (recur res group (next coll))))
      (if (seq curr)
        (conj res curr)
        res))))
```

in repl:

```
user> (map (partial group-loop 2)
           [[]
            nil
            [1 2 3 1 2 3]
            [1 2 3 1 2 3 2]
            [2 1 2 3 1 2 3]
            [1 3 4 1 3 4]])

;;([] [] 
;; [[1 2] [3 1 2] [3]] 
;; [[1 2] [3 1 2] [3 2]] 
;; [[2] [1 2] [3 1 2] [3]] 
;; [[1 3 4 1 3 4]])
```

Though it looks a bit too verbose, it still has some rather important advantages: first of all it is kind of classic (which i find a pro rather than con), second: it is fast (according to my benchmark about 3 times faster than `reduce` variant, and 6 to 10 times faster than `partition` variant)

also you can make it more clojurish with some minor tweaks, returning lazy collection as clojure's sequence operating functions do:

```
(defn group-lazy [delim coll]
  (loop [curr [] coll coll]
    (if (seq coll)
      (let [curr (conj curr (first coll))]
        (if (= delim (first coll))
          (cons curr (lazy-seq (group-lazy delim (rest coll))))
          (recur curr (next coll))))
      (when (seq curr) [curr]))))

user> (map (partial group-lazy 2)
           [[]
            nil
            [1 2 3 1 2 3]
            [1 2 3 1 2 3 2]
            [2 1 2 3 1 2 3]
            [1 3 4 1 3 4]])

;;(nil nil 
;; ([1 2] [3 1 2] [3]) 
;; ([1 2] [3 1 2] [3 2]) 
;; ([2] [1 2] [3 1 2] [3]) 
;; [[1 3 4 1 3 4]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way by combining two `partition` variants. First use `partition-by` to divide at instances of 2, then take two and two of those partitions with `partition-all` and join them together using `concat`.

```
(->> [0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1]
     (partition-by (partial = 2))               ;;((0 1) (2) (0 1) (2) (0 1))
     (partition-all 2)                          ;;(((0 1) (2)) ((0 1) (2)) ((0 1)))
     (mapv (comp vec (partial reduce concat)))) ;;[[0 1 2] [0 1 2] [0 1]]
```

Although note that if the input starts on a 2 the returned partitions will also start with 2s, not end on them as here.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, works as requested for all inputs:

```
(reduce #(let [last-v (peek %1)]
           (if (= 2 (last last-v))
             (conj %1 [%2])
             (conj (pop %1) (conj last-v %2))))
        [[]]
        [2 2 0 1 2 3 4 2 2 0 1 2 2])

=> [[2] [2] [0 1 2] [3 4 2] [2] [0 1 2] [2]]
```

While Magos has an elegant solution, it is unfortunately not complete, as he mentions.  So, the above should do the job using `reduce`.

We look at the most recently added element.  If it was a `2`, we create a new sub-vector (`(conj %1 [%2])`).  Otherwise, we add it to the last sub-vector.  Pretty simple really.  Existing functions like the `partition`s and `split`s are great for reusing when possible, but sometimes the best solution is a custom function, and in this case it's actually pretty clean.